# generic function operating on tagged disjoint union - why is type specification needed here?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm struggling to understand why a certain typecast helps here.

Here is the function:

```js
function getAttributeFromVerification<V extends Verification>(
  verification: V | null,
  attribute: keyof V['attributes']
) {
  // the verification may not exist at all
  if (verification == null) {
    return null
  }

  // the verification existing but missing the given attribute is a distinct error case
  return verification.attributes[attribute] || 'some value signifying attribute is missing'
}
```

Some details on types:

- `Verification` is a disjoint union that looks like `{ type: DisjointUnionTag, attributes: { ...properties unique to a given verification type } }`. So `EmailVerification` may look like `{ type: 'email', attributes: { email: 'test@123.com', someOtherEmailSpecificProperty: 'foo' }}`, whereas `AddressVerification` may look like `{ type: 'address', attributes: { street1: 'Foo', street2: 'Bar', city: '...', ... }}`, and `type Verification = EmailVerification | AddressVerification | ...other verifications`
- I want my function to be able to typecheck `attribute`s passed, such that I can do `getAttributeFromVerification<EmailVerification>(myEmailVerification, 'street2')` and get a type error since `street2` does not exist on `EmailVerification`'s attributes.
- The above function errors on the final line with `Type 'keyof V["attributes"]' cannot be used to index type EmailVerification | AddressVerification | ...etc.`

When casting `verification.attributes` to `(verification.attributes as V['attributes'])` everything typechecks properly. However, I have no idea why this works. If `verification` is a `V`, why isn't `verification.attributes` being recognized as `V['attributes']`? And why does explicitly typing it work?

Thanks, all!

Comment: Here's a [minimal reproducible example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEBvRAQwC4KBfRegPgAoo6MAaRAazt7YAnnGCJWGANoAiKtIC6ASkUUAUIkRQAdFUm95AbkQB6YzgBO5uOYCEfYaMRSA5FWfzEEKmDBwoiACNsRBASbCJNOEQYYjwGVXVPBBJ-KFonGTkPAF5NHSNTRDheKiFEiGT-c0RctL1DEzNi0tV6BKA) of this.  I think the answer is going to be something like "the compiler doesn't expect people to mix generics and concrete types like this, and you have to lead it through some different calculations to get it to verify type safety".  Looking for a related GitHub issue now.

Comment: Haven't found a definitely relevant issue.  Maaaaybe [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760) is related?  I'd be interested in getting an official answer for why this is happening so I might file an issue myself if you don't.

Comment: Thanks for digging! 

> an indexed access T[K] is permitted only if K is known to be assignable to keyof T, and string is not.

This makes me think the issue lies not with `K` (aka `attributes` for me) but with the fact that `verification.attributes` is not being recognized as a `V['attributes']`.

Comment: Okay I think [Microsoft/TypeScript#17110](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17110) is related but it's listed as "working as intended".  I commented in there and I'll see if anyone replies.  If not, I'll probably file a new issue

Comment: Playing with my code more, `verification.attributes` is indeed being recognized as `Verification['attributes']` instead of `V`['attributes']` (from `V extends Verification`). 

I'm not sure if this is a bug. When I have some spare time I will file an issue!

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from Typescript collaborator @jack-williams](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194):

> Property access and element access return the corresponding property type of the constraint, so `w.x` and `w['x']` have type `A`, this is why the the access with `k` fails. **Once you fall back to something concrete you can't later index with something generic.**
>
> The access `x[k]` works because it uses the declared type which is a generic indexed access type which has been sufficiently deferred, therefore retaining its 'generic-ness'.

The linked Github thread also includes a comment regarding how this *may* be improved in the future such that the property access is correctly inferred as expected.