# Type guard expands generic to all possible values?

Tags: typescript, generics

Here's a simplified code snippet to reproduce my issue:

```
type Supported = 'foo'|'bar';
type State = {
  [K in Supported]?: K[]
}
function test<T extends keyof State>(state: State, type: T) {
  const arr = state[type];
  if (!arr) {
    return;
  }
  return arr[0];
}
function test2<T extends keyof State>(state: State, type: T) {
  const arr = state[type] as T[]|undefined;
  if (!arr) {
    return;
  } 
  return arr[0];
}
```

In the first function, arr's type is State[T] before the if block. It becomes "foo"[] | "bar"[] afterwards.
In test2, I cast arr to the actual value type of the state manually and the return value type is correct.

It looks like the generic type T is lost after the type guard filtering out undefined. Is this behavior expected?

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrmMB7ATsCATKBeKByAMySTwB88AjAQxTwG4AoUSWYK9HKAbwaigG0A0lACWAO1gJkaTAF0A-AC4og-rIYBfBgThiAxsBFIJ6AM7AAPABUoEAB7oxGU1ADWEEEgKt2EAHwAFOa+yjBs6AA0UMwQylYAlNy8UHrG5lA0KJzB6Pwxsox8It4BAISZiTx8fCgQwHAoYoVQWjV1DRKZ-AAMBVAA9P0pacAZKCjKAERESJNqUKRQk9Qoc+paOvqGxtEQ5gBM1rYOEE4u7p7eYb6BObE+kdHg9wlJfKli6ZnZ4RB5z7IMi4rGpSLoMBACOJMM1ilAyhU3tVavVGs0NFBkiiOmMUD0+oNhp9Rpk4mpNAwgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on here is similar to [this reported issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17110) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718622/generic-function-operating-on-tagged-disjoint-union-why-is-type-specification)... when you read a property from a [constrained generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) (e.g., `State[K]` where `K extends keyof State`), the generic type gets widened to its constraint (so `K` becomes `keyof State`, and `State[K]` is evaluated as `State[keyof State]` which is `"foo"[] | "bar"[] | undefined`.  This isn't exactly *wrong* in your case, it is true that `state[type]` is of type `"foo"[] | "bar"[] | undefined`... it's just not as *specific* as you'd like.

You want to see `state[type]` as something like `K[] | undefined`.  But the compiler just doesn't do this for you... it would require some higher-order type analysis that the compiler doesn't know how to perform.  It would have to be able to calculate that `Exclude<State[K], undefined>[0]` is equivalent to `K`, and it can't.

The type assertion you're using in `test2` seems like a reasonable workaround to me.

Another possibility is to widen the type of the `state` parameter from `State` to something that it is forced to treat as `K[] | undefined` when you index into it.  For example, something like `Partial<Record<K, K[]>>`.  The only problem with using that directly is that the compiler will use both the `type` and `state` parameters to infer `K`, and that could widen `K` up to the full `keyof State`.  We only want to use `type` to infer `K`, so it would be good to tell the compiler to use the type parameters in `state` [in a "non-inferential" way](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  One way to do that, [according to a language maintainer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731), is to replace `K` with `K & {}` in the places where we don't want inference to happen.  That leads us to this:

```
function test3<K extends keyof State>(
  state: Partial<Record<K & {}, K[]>>,
  type: K
) {
  const arr = state[type]; 
  // const arr: { [P in K]?: P[] | undefined; }[K]
  if (!arr) {
    return;
  }
  // const arr: K[]
  return arr[0];

}
```

Now the compiler understands that after `undefined` is eliminated, `arr` will be of type `K[]`.  And thus the return type of `test3` is inferred as `K`.  Hooray!  Yes, that's a lot of hoops to jump through compared to your type assertion, so in practice I'd probably just assert and move on.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrmMB7ATsCATKBeKAiAMySTygB98AjAQxTwG4AoR0SWYa9HKAbygG0A0lACWAO1gJkaTAF0A-AC4og-rKgBfJowDGSMQGdgUA8pgcuuHoyhQiSZf0LE8AGnz28s1zag0Ujnj+XoxazARwYjrAIvpQ6EYAPMIQAB7oYhgGUADWECBIBOycEAB8ABRGJWYWEO6sEMqCAJS8vnqGxrQo3FXo-A2yTLYiReUAhN2t1ra2KBDAcChiw5q+84vLUN38AAxDUAD0h1AdRtsoAR4uauRUtHhqoSwQRpXuziTN2hFRMXEJYAAJmSUDSGSyuXyhWK6AqfUasLq8XAiJabVsZy6l16tQGqPU1GyqnUFEiGAgBHEmFWoygEymGNmGyWK18GnWC1ZFxQewOx1O+nO3WUABUnhzAUD3tcvj9ItFYhJAQBmUHgiCZbJ5ApFcwlCq+BHKAAKtBi1AANokAEoQPQoDCggBkvA07hJpVKPlsDSajGm7SF2J6uAR+MgQ18AqxPOUfH4JtEEkEClNtzJmUp1Iw9E0QlkvjpDMugdmUBZy1WHNsMeDcZUTzmXK2O32TElr2AKplQQe30YQA)

Comment: This is very tricky but makes sense. Thanks for the thorough response!

Answer (score 1):

Actually your first example is inferred properly, the typecast and array type  in second example are a bit inaccurate. In your concrete case it doesn't matter, as you only return the first element. First things first, let's look at `test`:

#### `test` function

`State[T]` is the same as  `"foo"[] | "bar"[] | undefined`. You can also write it like this:

```
State[T] -> State["foo" | "bar"] -> State["foo"] | State["bar"] -> "foo"[] | "bar"[] 

=> "foo"[] | "bar"[] | undefined (optional properties possible)
```

So it is correct that `arr` has the type `"foo"[] | "bar"[]` at the end of your function, `arr[0]` type `"foo" | "bar"`, because your if-block excludes the undefined value. IntelliSense displayed type representations can be a bit confusing, as sometimes  they end up more verbose/granular, sometimes more compact/unresolved. The canonical type for the compiler is the same though.

#### Comparison with `test2`

In the beginning, I said that your casted array type is slightly inaccurate. Lets assume, that we return the whole array in `test1` and `test2` (not only the first element), to illustrate the issue.

New function signatures of `test` and `test2`

```
// test signature
<T extends Supported>(state: State, type: T): State[T]
// test2 signature
<T extends Supported>(state: State, type: T): T[] | undefined
```

Test case:

```
// define some variables
declare const state: State;
declare const stateType: "foo" | "bar"; 

// invoke functions
test(state, stateType); // return type: "foo"[] | "bar"[] | undefined
test2(state, stateType); // return type: Supported[] | undefined
```

Results:

```
const test_sample1: "foo"[] | "bar"[] | undefined = ["foo", "foo"] // works
const test_sample2: "foo"[] | "bar"[] | undefined = ["foo", "bar"] // <-- error!
const test2_sample1: Supported[] | undefined = ["foo", "bar"] // works
const test2_sample2: Supported[] | undefined = ["foo", "foo"] // works
```

So with your manual cast in `test2` you could return `["foo", "bar"]`, which would not be possible with `test`. Part of the reason is, that following is not the same:

```
"foo"[] | "bar"[] !== ("foo"|"bar")[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrmMB7ATsCATKBeKAiAMySTygB98AjAQxTwG4AoUSWYa9HKAbygG0A0lACWAO1gJkaTAF0A-AC4oAvjKgBfJs3DQY7dAIggAzlwDWRpATYcI9KAHoH+IiXJVaebaz23DIAH1XLl90PkJiPBl7JxdI1Xc4UQwIAjFMb119CH8AmhQQ7PD8qJjnPBKEiiSUtNEMlizbADVqABs4CFNcUIg+CxArG3Rox3LXPCqPOima1PSMRkYCJIBjYGEkcXRjYAAeABUoCAAPdGTTAaHegD4ACl3bJV6AGihGpQOASh5GKChVltdlBaAVcI8wo1on8RNY7gBCUE-bgw-4oCDAOAoURMf7qY5tYzQFH-f6gsrDPoHGRvADuwmAAAskHBgFA5nVMG8idB6mcoG10qiAUC2cAALZgLigvgABlGsXgiFQ6EWpKg6Mx2JBKBQuI0jHUSxWonWm22XWAACZDsczhALlArtZbg9ss9sm8PlBvr9-oDRMDQVwIX0oSDTAdZsl5vUMPrhHDEbrkcLNVicTCjWiMRmdXrDUsUqs2rRoAHgaGPbYmMXS+iRYG2aGDjolBE3BQKp4tDtgG7bNzsq3IF8mH2rQP0EPbCOIGOlhWxZaAsZqJK2hAAIztiZTbszNTVGOcrC4cITN4dqJjKC01BmYyMJfvFdrjcQK27+JH6aTX8cgsXAXpEV4lGosQQLqqDPqKr67Faq7rmAm47hIyrSBg0a1EB57XmBngQc494oI+sFNvB1pIR+X7oVIqrYbGmDAfhcQkERd4PsYQA)

Hope, it helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

I was only considering passing the string literal 'foo' or 'bar' into test functions. If passing in a variable of type 'foo'|'bar', your described issue would happen and casting can be inaccurate.